# Did the Jedi Temple Guards defend the Temple against Operation: Knightfall?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, revenge-of-the-sith, order-66

The [Jedi Temple Guards](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_Guard) had one job, defending the Coruscant Jedi Temple

However, they did not seem to appear in *Revenge of the Sith*, even when the Temple was under direct attack from Darth Vader and the 501st.

Did they attempt to defend the Temple and we just didn't see it? Were the preemptively dealt with somehow? Did they defect to the Empire? Did something else happen?

I'm fine with answers from both canons.

Comment: They went rogue, of course.

Comment: At least one did (go rogue), right? The Grand Inquisitor?

Comment: Maybe. I thought the clear implication of the Inquisitor appearing as a Temple Guard was that he had been one.

Comment: @Jonah We don't know when he left though, It could have been years before Order 66.

Answer (score 14):

The film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) indicates that the Jedi Temple was lightly defended at the time of the attack, with the majority of active Jedi Knights and Masters off-world directing clone troopers in battle.

There are a couple of scenes in the book that don't appear in the film:

- **The Jedi placed the Temple into lockdown**

> *“Master Ti and Gate Master Jurokk will direct the Temple’s defense,”
>   he said as he reached the others. “We are shutting down all nav
>   beacons and signal lights, we have armed the older Padawans, and all
>   blast doors are sealed and code-locked.” His gaze swept the Masters.
>   “It’s time to go.”*

- **Anakin Skywalker betrayed the Gate Master (and opened the main door)**

> *Gate Master Jurokk sprinted through the empty vaulted hallway,
>   clattering echoes of his footsteps making him sound like a platoon.
>   The main doors of the Temple were slowly swinging inward in answer to
>   the code key punched into the outside lockpad. The Gate Master had
>   seen him on the monitor. Anakin Skywalker. Alone.*
>
> ...
>
> *Jurokk looked past him now. The night beyond the Temple was full of
>   clones. Battalions of them. Brigades. Thousands.*
>
> *“Anakin,” he said slowly, “what’s going on? Something’s happened.
>   Something horrible. How bad is it-?”*
>
> *The last thing Jurokk felt was the emitter of a lightsaber*

Presumably then, the Jedi Temple Guards were slaughtered by the thousands of troops at Anakin's command.

Answer (score 1):

Head of the Jedi Temple Guards [Cin Drallig](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cin_Drallig#cite_note-Episode_III-1) fought Darth Vader during Operation Knightfall.

[Please note that while the video refers to the two Padawans as Drallig's students, that information is not confirmed.]

It is unknown if any other guards were present at the Temple during the attack.

Answer (score -1):

At least one Temple Guard was not killed. As of the canon TV series *Star Wars Rebels*, episode 2.17 ("Shroud of Darkness"), it was revealed that a Temple Guard present at Ahsoka Tano's trial became the Emperor's Grand Inquisitor, a Jedi-hunting wielder of the Dark Side of the Force.

Comment: Is there any evidence he was actually there during the attack, though?

Answer (score -1):

The Jedi temple guards are actually the reason there was any survivors in legends on the attack on the temple. Every single one of them fought to protect their fellow Jedi at cost, till Darth Vader started his assault on them, the guards were pushing back the 501st legion and the only reason the temple wasn't a complete slaughter as 80% of the Jedi was off world leaving only the too old to fight, too young to be at war and the temple guards. The 501st was outclassed and being driven out of the temple until Darth Vader killed Cin Dragllig and most of the other temple guards. In canon it's unclear what's happened as there's a few Jedi in legend that was slaughtered alongside the  temple guards which survived order 66 thanks to Disney remaking what's cannon and not.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this?